# How to make threads work in Series

Tags: android, multithreading, android-camera, previewcallback

I have created a **CameraApp**. And getting `byte[]` cameraPreviewCallback in `onPreviewFrame(byte byteArray[] , Camera camera)`

I am converting these `byteArray` to `rgb` and doing a lot of stuff too. So It is working slowly. So I think I should get benefit from `java.util.concurrent` package. But didn't find an easy way to handle what I want.

I want multiple threads to do my job serially but each time one can set `bitmap` to `surfaceView`. And also have to check that:

```
No Old byte of Array shouldn't be draw on surfaceView.
```

I think I have to write that code using a synchronize lock. And check for a boolean variable `isWorkingOnFrame` is `true`.

Can someone explain me how to use multiple threads in series but at one time one can do its work.

```
private android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback previewCallback = new android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback()
    {
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte abyte0[] , Camera camera)
        {   
            try
            {
               Thread.sleep(1L);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException interruptedexception)
            {
                return;
            }

            int[] rgbData =  YuvUtils.myDecodeGreyscale(abyte0, widthPreview, heightPreview, imageBrightness, nonGreencolorOffset, greenColorOffset);  ///it is working...

            editedBitmap.setPixels(rgbData, 0, widthPreview, 0, 0, widthPreview, heightPreview);

            if(CameraStatik.cameraId==CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            {   
                matrix.setRotate(270F);
            }

            finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(editedBitmap, 0, 0, widthPreview, heightPreview, matrix, true);

            if(saveCurrentFrame)
            {
                saveCurrentFrame =false;

                new BitmapSaver(ctx, finalBitmap).start();
            }

            drawView.setBitmapToDraw(finalBitmap);
        }
    };
```

I simply want to make this code work efficiently.

Comment: 1 word for you - [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

Answer (score 1):

Solve it in the java way! Use the [`Executor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface along with [`Runnable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html).

First, get a [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (which implements the `Executor` interface) with [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29), and then, put your Threads to work.

**Example:**

```
public YourClass extends Activity {
    // Other methods like onCreate() variable declarations and so on.
    // ...

    private void runOnThread() {
        Executor exe = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        exe.execute(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                // Do whatever you want to do.
            } 
        });
    }
    // Other methods...
    // ...
}
```

You can read more about `Executor` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

Or like it was said on the comments, you can take a look at [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) and on [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/threadpoolexecutor.html).

Comment: I have two question. How many thread are created by your code and they work parallely or serially.

Comment: You can create as many Threads as you want. And they will work each one at a time. They'll be placed in a queue. Once one finishes working, the next one on the queue will begin to work.

Comment: how could i handle to call setBitmap. Suppose ten threads created at a time. any suppose(third thread) draws bitmap and after 2 second thread 5 is calling setBitmap(it may have save the old set of bytes,how could i handle this.

Comment: If you create 10 Threads, they'll work only one at a time, so there'll be no concurrent calls to your `setBitmap()` method.

Comment: You're not supposed to put exactly as it is there, it's just an example. I'll try to fit it on your code.

Comment: Also note that there is no point of creating 10 threads if they are going to execute the tasks in series anyways... You'll be good with just one extra thread.

Comment: @Mauker Nice answer.  I have similar use case.  I need to load 6 large bitmap images when Activity starts.  So I would call runOnThread() in onCreate() to load the first image?  Then set up a second method, runOnThreadSecond() and call it in onCreate() after runOnThread() and so on for the remainder?